# Can I run a DELETE with a limit?

Tags: hsqldb

I need to run a query like the following in HSQLDB:

```
delete from mytable where username = ? and password = ? and name = ? limit 1;
```

Essentially, I'd like to only delete *one* row from the database at most, provided that row matches my above criteria. Is this possible in HSQLDB?

Comment: Why do you have multiple user with the same username and **hashed and salted** password? It is impossible to have two users with the same encrypted passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
delete from mytable where username = ? and password = ? and name = ? and rownum() <= 1
```

The expression `rownum() <= n` is also used to break down a huge delete or update into smaller chunks. For example deleting some 1000000 rows can be done in chunks of 100000 rows.